# Say a message for longer on alexa developer with python

Tags: message, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have a problem when I tell Alexa a long message, it can't capture my entire message.
When I am testing my skill on my cell phone and not on an echo device, my message is completely captured. But when I connect an eco device it doesn't work, the message cuts off before finishing

I had the idea of modifying the time, but I thought if it works on the cell phone when I execute the skill, that shouldn't be the problem.
What other solutions could be given?

Answer (score 0):

What type of duration are we talking about for the message you're looking to capture ?
And what slot type are you using for the intent which you're wanting the message to trigger ?

Lots of people try to use Alexa as a dictation device to capture large amounts of speech.  Alexa isn't designed to do this and so issues similar to what you're experiencing then arise.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for answering this question. I try to capture approximately 8 to 10 seconds maximum. And I am using the AMAZON.SearchQuery. As I mentioned before, I don't have any problems using the skill on my cell phone. The problem arises when I try my skill on the echo device. I also tried it on other echo devices and I have the same problem. I could notice that when a message is sent, since it is not an order with the same tone of voice, this is detrimental, but as I mentioned, when I use the cell phone the problem does not exist.
I appreciate the guidance you can give me.

Comment: I guess the Alexa app on a mobile device operates differently to a real, physical device.  If your speech isn't being fully captured then perhaps you're leaving gaps inbetween your words.  Alexa will assume you've finished speaking if there is a relatively short pause between words.  This all comes down to Alexa not being designed for dictation.